# Strange behaviour of bootstrap classes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am a newbie for bootstrap. I was just experimenting code like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8" style="background-color:red;">col1</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4" style="background-color:green;">col2</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

What is strange is that after some width the col1 just disappears. I wanted it to take whole 12 columns when it is small. Is there any wrong code i have done?

Comment: Try changing your row class to a container class. That could do it, because it seems like a row should not have, well, a second row, basically.

Comment: @Dan - It did not work!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just add "col-xs-12" to col2 otherwise it overlaps col1.

Comment: Isn't that implied if not listed?

Comment: Why does it overlap?? as both are defined for 2 different views.

Answer (score 0):

Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths greater than or equal to the breakpoint sizes, and override grid classes targeted at smaller devices.

**Screen size break points**

> col-xs-* for extra smaller screen (<768px)
>
> col-sm-* for smaller devices (≥768px)
>
> col-md-* for medium screen (≥992px)
>
> col-lg-* for larger screen (≥1200px)

**Sample code**

`<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-8" style="background-color:red;">col1</div>
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-4" style="background-color:green;">col2</div> </div>`

**Reference**

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid